# Spy on require in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, mocha.js, sinon

Inside a unit-test I want to verify whether the SUT calls `require` with a specific parameter. Basically my SUT is a small module with the following implementation:

```
module.exports = function () {
  require('foo');
};
```

I now want to write a test like this:

```
var sut = require('./sut');
it('requires foo.', function () {
  sut();
  expect( ??? );
});
```

So the question is: How do I verify whether `require` was called with the correct parameters? I tried it using a Sinon.js spy:

```
var spy = sinon.spy(require);
sut();
expect(spy.callCount).to.be.equal(1);
expect(spy.calledWithExactly('foo')).to.be(true);
require.restore();
```

But this doesn't work. When I run my test, Mocha tells me:

> Error: expected 0 to equal 1

What am I doing wrong, and how can I fix it?

PS: I do not *need* to work with Sinon.js, so if another module is better suited for my case, everything else is fine as well.

Answer (score 4):

There is a module called `proxyquire` with which you can override dependencies for unit testing purpopses: https://npmjs.org/package/proxyquire

Your unit test may then look like this:

```
var proxyquire =  require('proxyquire');

var sut = proxyquire('./sut', { 'foo': function(){ /* insert test code here */ });
```

I'm not sure if that is exactly what you want, but maybe you'll find it helpful.

Comment: proxyquire would be great if I wanted it for the whole time - but I just need it for one test. With proxyquire I have no possibility to reconfigure this for each test, unfortunately. So, hence: Good hint, but not matching for my scenario.

Answer (score 1):

You could try [rewire](https://github.com/jhnns/rewire). It gives you private access to modules for testing purposes. Then you could inspect the `module.children`-variable to check for the dependency.

Given you want to check if module `a.js` requires `b.js` it would look like:

```
var rewire = require("rewire");
var a = rewire("./a.js"); // using rewire instead of require

var pathToB = require.resolve("./b.js");
var aModule = a.__get__("module"); // leaking the private module-variable

assert.ok(aModule.children.some(function (module) {
    return module.filename === pathToB;
}));
```

Comment: I just found out that `b.js` should not be in the `require.cache`, otherwise it doesn't appear in the `children`-array.

Comment: If `require("./b.js")` doesn't happen on module startup you could inject your own `require()` via `a.__set__("require", requireMock)`